# There is a unity error CS0176: Member 'PlayerSaving.levels' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity says that my Code has a error:

Member 'PlayerSaving.levels' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
PlayerData.cs(13,17)

Here the code:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
public int level = 0;
public int coins = 0;

public PlayerData (PlayerSaving player)
{
    level = player.levels;
    coins = player.savedCoins;
}
}
```

and

```
public class PlayerSaving : MonoBehaviour
{
public static int levels = 0;
public static int savedCoins = 0;

void Update()
{
    if (levels != Endlevel.level)
    {
        levels = Endlevel.level;
    }
    if (savedCoins != SC_2DCoin.totalCoins)
    {
        savedCoins = SC_2DCoin.totalCoins;
    }
}

public void SavePlayer()
{
    SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
}

public void LoadPlayer()
{
    PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();

    levels = data.level;
    savedCoins = data.coins;
}
}
```

I need for my variables the static to access with more scripts the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `levels` field in `PlayerSaving` class as static member, you must access it directly from class not from an instance object of that class. like this example :

```
public PlayerData (PlayerSaving player)
{
    level = PlayerSaving.levels;
    coins = PlayerSaving.savedCoins;
}
```

or make the fields instance member

```
public class PlayerSaving : MonoBehaviour
{
// remove static keyword
public int levels = 0;
public int savedCoins = 0;
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked. I used the first one